# Do the following sequences converge in R^3

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

does xk = (√k+1 − √k, 7)converge to a limit in R3?

I know  a sequence is convergent iff its coordinates are convergent.

√k + 1 −√k = (√k+1 + √k)/(√k+1 + √k)
           = (√k+1 − √k)/(√k+1 + √k)
           = 1/(√k+1 + √k) -> 0 as k->0

7->7 as k->ꝏ 
So xk -> (0,7) as k->ꝏ

does xk=(√k+1 − √k)/2 , 6) converge to a limit in R^3?

would I proceed in a similar way for this sequence?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$? The examples you give are couples, not triples. But yes, you can use the same approach.

Comment: Please learn the basics of formatting questions. Do you mean $x_k=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference